# How can I add lead status in vicidial script dynamically?

Tags: limesurvey, vici

I'm using a combination of `lime survey` and `vicidial` in order to display scripts dynamically. I need to inject the lead status (NEW,CALLBK,DNC,etc...) in the script, but I can't find a way to do this.

This is the script in vicidial:

```
src="https://limesurvey/index.php/153496?newtest=Y&lang=es-CL&lead_status=--A--[ADD STATUS HERE]--B--" style="background-color:transparent;" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" id="popupFrame" name="popupFrame"  width="--A--script_width--B--" height="--A--script_height--B--" STYLE="z-index:17">
```

How can I inject the last lead status in the `lead_status=--A--[ADD STATUS HERE]--B--` variable?

I already tried `lead_status=--A--status--B--`

Comment: lead_status is a question you want to prefil?

Comment: Check this https://manual.limesurvey.org/URL_fields#Prefilling_a_survey_using_GET_parameters and the type of question you want to prefill

Comment: @EduardLuca No, I haven't. Seems that it is actually not possible. If you have any other information, please let me know.